# What I'm missing in this simulation?

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

I'm trying to write a VHDL code for a keyboard driver for that I need read 8 bit out of 11 bit vector, to keep things clear here is the process that reads the input signals (there are signal CLK and Data).

```
KEYBOARD_SYNC : process(CLK,SYSRESET)
        begin 
            if (CLK'event and CLK='1') then 
                KEYBOARD_CLK_VECTOR <=   KEYBOARD_CLK_VECTOR( 6 downto 0 ) & KEYBOARD_CLK;
                    RECEIVING_FLAG <='0';
                    if ( KEYBOARD_CLK_VECTOR = x"F0" ) then  -- Falling edge 
                        KEYBOARD_DATA_VECTOR <= KEYBOARD_DATA_VECTOR( 9 downto 0 ) & KEYBOARD_DATA;-- shifting 
                        BIT_COUNTER <= BIT_COUNTER + 1 ; 

                    end if; 

                    if( BIT_COUNTER = 11 ) then 
                        RECEIVING_FLAG <='1';
                        TEMP_WORD <= KEYBOARD_DATA_VECTOR( 8 downto 1 );
                        BIT_COUNTER <=0 ;
                        KEYBOARD_DATA_VECTOR <= (others =>'1');
                    end if ;

            end if ; 
end process KEYBOARD_SYNC; 

 PROCESSING  : process ( CLK ,SYSRESET ) 
        begin 
            if ( CLK'event and CLK ='1') then 
                if ( RECEIVING_FLAG = '1') then 
                    ACTUAL_WORD <= TEMP_WORD; 
                end if ;
            end if ;
end process PROCESSING;
```

To run the simulation I wrote a testbench that should send a `0xF0`, this value should be save in ACTUAL_WORD, here is the part of the testbench that's should do that:

```
-- Timing variables 
constant CLK_PERIOD: time := 10 ns;
constant KEYBOARD_CLK_PERIOD: time := 80 us;

...................................................



    KEYBOARD_PROCESS : process 
    BEGIN 


        -- BREAK Code 
            KEYBOARD_CLK <= '1';
            KEYBOARD_DATA <= '0';
        wait for (KEYBOARD_CLK_PERIOD/2);
            KEYBOARD_CLK <= '0';            --Start  Bit  always 0 
        wait for (KEYBOARD_CLK_PERIOD/2);
            KEYBOARD_CLK <= '1';                
            KEYBOARD_DATA <= '1';           -- Sending a break code 0xF0 
        wait for (KEYBOARD_CLK_PERIOD/2);
            KEYBOARD_CLK <= '0';            -- 0  Bit 
        wait for (KEYBOARD_CLK_PERIOD/2);
            KEYBOARD_CLK <= '1';
        wait for (KEYBOARD_CLK_PERIOD/2);
            KEYBOARD_CLK <= '0';            -- 1  Bit 
        wait for (KEYBOARD_CLK_PERIOD/2);
            KEYBOARD_CLK <= '1';
        wait for (KEYBOARD_CLK_PERIOD/2);
            KEYBOARD_CLK <= '0';            -- 2  Bit 
        wait for (KEYBOARD_CLK_PERIOD/2);
            KEYBOARD_CLK <= '1';
        wait for (KEYBOARD_CLK_PERIOD/2);
            KEYBOARD_CLK <= '0';            -- 3  Bit 
        wait for (KEYBOARD_CLK_PERIOD/2);
            KEYBOARD_DATA<= '0';
            KEYBOARD_CLK <= '1';
        wait for (KEYBOARD_CLK_PERIOD/2);
            KEYBOARD_CLK <= '0';            -- 4  Bit 
        wait for (KEYBOARD_CLK_PERIOD/2);
            KEYBOARD_CLK <= '1';
        wait for (KEYBOARD_CLK_PERIOD/2);
            KEYBOARD_CLK <= '0';            -- 5  Bit 
        wait for (KEYBOARD_CLK_PERIOD/2);
            KEYBOARD_CLK <= '1';
        wait for (KEYBOARD_CLK_PERIOD/2);
            KEYBOARD_CLK <= '0';            -- 6  Bit 
        wait for (KEYBOARD_CLK_PERIOD/2);
            KEYBOARD_CLK <= '1';
        wait for (KEYBOARD_CLK_PERIOD/2);
            KEYBOARD_CLK <= '0';            -- 7  Bit 
        wait for (KEYBOARD_CLK_PERIOD/2);
            KEYBOARD_DATA<= '1';
            KEYBOARD_CLK <= '1';
        wait for (KEYBOARD_CLK_PERIOD/2);
            KEYBOARD_CLK <= '0';            -- Parity Bit           
        wait for (KEYBOARD_CLK_PERIOD/2);
            KEYBOARD_CLK <= '1';
        wait for (KEYBOARD_CLK_PERIOD/2);
            KEYBOARD_CLK <= '0';            -- Stop Bit  always 1   
        wait for (KEYBOARD_CLK_PERIOD/2);
            KEYBOARD_CLK <= '1';
        wait for (KEYBOARD_CLK_PERIOD/2);
end process KEYBOARD_PROCESS;
```

The result is : 
[image: rotated]
(clickable)

The problem is that I keep reading `0xE1` instead of `0xF0` everything else is working fine and I can't figure out why I'm missing this Bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the periodic pattern of 0xF0 as 0xE1 looks like a 1-bit shift, and that is probably caused by the test bench generating the clock (`KEYBOARD_CLK`) and data (`KEYBOARD_DATA`) at the same time.

In a hardware design, output data is generated as a result of clock, so there will be at least one delta cycle delay between the rising edge of clock and the new data, but the current test bench design generates clock and data at the same time with:

```
KEYBOARD_CLK <= '1';
KEYBOARD_DATA <= '0';
```

The waveform therefor looks familiar, but the signal flow actually lacks a delta cycle delay between clock and data so data is ready one cycle earlier than expected from the waveform, causing a 1-bit shift.  That is however not shown in the present waveform view, which is probably the puzzling part.  ModelSim can show the lack of delta cycle, but that is not default.

It is usually a good idea to follow a general design methodology also in test bench design, in order to keep to a single common design practice, which makes reading code and waveforms easier.

So in the test bench, make a process that generates the clock, and then make a process that generates the data based on the clock, just as with hardware designs.  This can be done like:

```
CLK_PROCESS : process 
BEGIN 
  KEYBOARD_CLK <= '1';
  wait for (KEYBOARD_CLK_PERIOD/2);
  KEYBOARD_CLK <= '1';
  wait for (KEYBOARD_CLK_PERIOD/2);
end process;

DATA_PROCESS : process
BEGIN
  KEYBOARD_DATA <= '0';
  for i in 1 to 5 loop  -- Number of cycles with same data
      wait until rising_edge(KEYBOARD_CLK);
  end loop;
  ...
  KEYBOARD_DATA <= '1';
  for i in 1 to 5 loop  -- Number of cycles with same data
      wait until rising_edge(KEYBOARD_CLK);
  end loop;
  ...
end process;
```

Adjust loops for repeated data as appropriate for the desired test pattern.

Comment: thanks for your help! that's smart and efficient way to write the test bench! thanks again!